# Write contents of InputStream to a RichTextItem and attach to a Notes document in Java

Tags: java, attachment, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am able to attach a file to `RichTextItem` of a domino document that I receive as an `InputStream`. Below is the code snippet:

```
attachDocument(InputStream is){
    .....
    File attFile = saveInputStr(is);
    Document attdoc = testdb.createDocument();
    attDoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "formAttachment");
    RichTextItem rti = (RichTextItem) attDoc.getFirstItem("attachment");
    rti.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", attFile .getPath(), attFile .getName());
    .....
}
```

This works fine. But what if I don't want to write the file to disk, like I save it to a `File` i.e. `attFile` in the above snippet. Is there a way that to write the contents of `InputStream` to a file (may be using some notes document) and attach it with out saving to disk.

Comment: Where are you getting the `InputStream is`? I mean what is the source of it, another `embeddedObj.getInputStream()` or something else?

Comment: sorry for replying late..ya I get the input stream like this.. I got the solution for this. I have answered it below..

Answer (score 3):

I actually found solution for my question. Maybe it will be helpful for someone

```
attachDocument(InputStream is){
        .....
        //File attFile = saveInputStr(is);
        Document attdoc = testdb.createDocument();
        attDoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "formAttachment");
        //RichTextItem rti = (RichTextItem) attDoc.getFirstItem("attachment");
        //rti.embedObject(EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT, "", attFile .getPath(), attFile .getName());
        attDoc.getFirstItem("attachment");
        Stream stream = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession().createStream();
        stream.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
        MIMEEntity me = attDoc.createMIMEEntity("attachment"); 
        me.setContentFromBytes(stream, "application/pdf", MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT);
        is.close();
        attdoc.save();
        .....
    }
```

Comment: Hi! The DominoUtils and IOUtils belong o wich packages?

Answer (score 2):

Via the JAVA API (or LotusScript, COM) I don't see a way to add an attachment to a rich text item using anything but the embedObject method.  And unfortunately the embedObject method only takes a string pointing to the file location to be imported.  Without a way to pass in an actual object it seems you are required to have the file on disk and pass the path to that file.

Comment: This is correct. Our methodology is generally to create a folder on the file system and clean up and delete it when done.