# Poi4Xpages - write file to document during postGeneration

Tags: apache-poi, xpages, lotus-domino

as per a suggestion recently received from Stwissel, I am using the following code to convert a file to mime and attach to a notes document during the post generation process of POI4Xpages.

EDITED NEW CODE:

The following code attaches to document, but throws an error: 502 Bad Gateway - The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

```
public void saveExcel(Workbook a, Document newDoc) throws NotesException, IOException{

    newDoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Provider");

    // Create the stream
    Session session = DominoUtils.getCurrentSession();
    Stream stream = session.createStream();
    // Write the workbook to a ByteArrayOutputStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    a.write(bos);
    // Convert the output stream to an input stream
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
    stream.setContents(is);



MIMEEntity m = newDoc.createMIMEEntity("body");
MIMEHeader header = m.createHeader("content-disposition");
header.setHeaderVal("Mime attachment");
m.setContentFromBytes(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel", MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY); 
m.decodeContent();
newDoc.save(true, true);
}
```

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();

// Do not automatically convert MIME to rich text
session.setConvertMIME(false);
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Provider");
var body:NotesMIMEEntity = doc.createMIMEEntity();
var header:NotesMIMEHeader = body.createHeader("Subject");
header.setHeaderVal("MIME attachment");
if (stream.open("c:\\notes\\data\\abc.xlsx", "binary")) {
    if (stream.getBytes() != 0) {
        body.setContentFromBytes(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
    } else requestScope.status = "File was not found.";
} else requestScope.status = "Could not open file.";
stream.close();
doc.save(true, true);
// Restore conversion
session.setConvertMIME(true);
```

However, this code is only attaching a file which is already stored on the server's local directory. How can I get this code to take the POI fileOutputStream and attach that?

Comment: Your example is missing the code you're using for POI.

Comment: Hi, the code for poi works just fine. I'm really only interested in the post generation attachment to a notes document. The poi already generates an .xlsx file, all i need is to determine how to write poi to a notes stream? I haven't been able to achieve that.

Comment: The answer to this stackoverflow should help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425810/write-contents-of-inputstream-to-a-richtextitem-and-attach-to-a-notes-document-i

Comment: I definitely CAN attach an inputStream's contents to the document (its just that I can only figure out how to do this with a file on the local system)

eg.
var is = new java.io.FileInputStream("c:\\notes\\abc.xlsx");  
var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
stream.setContents(is);

What I cant figure out how to do is set the output of POI (via the postGeneration process) to the inputStream.

eg. cant make the code below work

var file = new java.io.File("file.xlsx");
var is = new java.io.FileInputStream(file);
var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
stream.setContents(is);

Comment: First: you aren't posting what error message you got. So it's hard to guess. As said before - check the link I've posted. You try to pass an InputStream as argument to .setContent() which isn't valid. You've to create a byte array and pass that as the argument.

Comment: There is no error message (It just doesn't do anything). And yes, i can pass java.io.FileInputStream to stream.setContent(). That does work. To clarify, what I am having trouble with is setting the output of poi to an inputStream

Comment: So you mean you have a Workbook object (via WorkbookProcessor.processWorkbook())? As said, still missing the code you're using.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14540635/2065611 ?

Comment: this is the route i am trying to take, but that answer doesn't go into detail about how I cant get a handle on the generated file (in memory) and pass it to the fileInputStream. How do you get a handle on the file in POI's postGeneration() method?

Answer (score 1):

It's a mix of what what Knut and I've commented about. The important part is that you'll use the `write()` method to pass the workbook data to an output stream.

```
// Create the stream
Stream stream = session.createStream();
// Write the workbook (you haven't clarified) to a ByteArrayOutputStream
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(bos);
// Convert the output stream to an input stream
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
stream.setContents(is);
```

Comment: I think there is a little bit of a mix up. I'm only writing code for the POI4Xpages postGeneration() event (and that's currently in javascript not java). I'm not using a bean to generate the document, its just a few bookmark tags. That's why I've been saying there is no code.

Comment: https://guedebyte.wordpress.com/2013/01/25/poi-4-xpages-version-1-1-0-released/ - the end of this blog post shows that the "workbook" variable is available.

Comment: Code is along these lines <wgpoi:spreadsheet id="spreadsheet1"
  downloadFileName="abc.xlsx">
  <wgpoi:this.templateSource>
   <wgpoi:resourcetemplate fileName="abc.xlsx"></wgpoi:resourcetemplate>
  </wgpoi:this.templateSource>
  <wgpoi:this.spreadsheets>
   <wgpoi:table create="false" name="Sheet1">
    <wgpoi:this.cellValues>
     <wgpoi:cellBookmark name="Amount1">
      <wgpoi:this.value><![CDATA["Amount1"]]></wgpoi:this.value>
     </wgpoi:cellBookmark>
    </wgpoi:this.cellValues>
   </wgpoi:table>
  </wgpoi:this.spreadsheets></wgpoi:this.spreadsheet>

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look and get back

Comment: Here's a link how to use Java from SSJS http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_Java#Tips+for+accessing+Java+via+SSJS

Comment: Is it possible to do what I want just in SSJS? getting the file to an input stream?

Comment: SSJS is in fact Java (it's a bad IBM-mutation of "something" for making things "simple" which I personally wouldn't advise to use). If you want the underlying Java object you'll need some Java.

Comment: Use a bean. SSJS has NO, ZERO, ZILCH advantage here. You only risk "variable guessing". It isn't that hard. In POI4XPages to write to a stream, not a file. That the stream you were writing to is a FileOutputstream is your choice

Comment: Thanks to you both for the help. I'll give the java a shot and get back to you with the results. On a side note, what do you mean that writing to a fileOutputStream is a choice? What else could I write to?? Thanks

Comment: Ok, modified a bit (see edited question), and the code now attaches the file to the document. But, it also throws a 502 error saying the server returned an invalid or incomplete response. Any ideas?

Comment: also, it generates 2 notes documents??